# File conversion in OCaml

Tags: parsing, ocaml, text-parsing

I am an almost complete OCaml newbie, but have some functional programming knowledge.
I am looking for a conceptual way of converting between two specification patterns.

1 2 "tau1"
1 3 "h1"
2 1 "h1"

into

1 tau1:2, h1:3;
2 h1:1;

The files are typically much larger.
I guess I can use a record type and read the input file line for line, 
then write to the other file.
But is there any better way?
Like using Ocamlyacc or something similar for parsing and converting?
Or anything else?

Answer (score 5):

It all depends on you current and future needs.

Learn parsing tools if you think you will have opportunities to reuse this knowledge.

On the other hand, the file format you need to parse seems simple, so if the format won't evolve it will be faster to write by hand a dedicated parser to this format.

Comment: Just what I was going to say! In fact, unless this is mostly an OCaml learning exercise (which would be great), this is something you can do in one or two lines of awk or python.

Comment: This is actually both a learning exercise (that' why I chose OCaml) and something I need SOON. I guess I might as well follow your advice and use awk or python, and then try it in OCaml when I have more time.I guess I should learn awk now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your data seems very simple so `Scanf.fscanf` can parse one line to each. The below code reads one line and gives tuple of values.

```
let ic = open_in "data.txt" in
  Scanf.fscanf "%d %d %s\n" (fun index value key -> (index, value, key))
```

Format specification is similar to C's `scanf`. If you want to remove double quote in `key`, replace `"%s"` into `"\"%[0-9a-aZ-Z]\""`.

There is still the running out of memory problem, but the solution may be in your mind.